# manual random selection, how?

Tags: statistics

Thas a question for my test in one hour...how do I do that? I have tried to find it online but no way...any help please?

Suppose that a simple random sample of 20 of the Aucklanders surveyed is to be
selected for further in-depth interviews about the new Auckland Council. Each
person surveyed is allocated an identification number from 1 to 300. Use the row
of random digits below to select the first 5 people. Start at the beginning of the
row and use consecutive groups of digits.

38905 93159 25252 29004 50592 73607

Here are the answer choices.

The first five Aucklanders sampled had identification numbers:

(1) 38, 90, 59, 31 and 25

(2) 389, 59, 315, 925 and 252

(3) 59, 252, 290, 45 and 273

(4) 389, 931, 252, 290 and 505

(5) 59, 252, 290, 45 and 59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the row of random numbers and take three at a time. If the three-digit number you get isn't in the range 1-300, skip it. So, the first three digits are 389, which isn't an identification number in the appropriate range: skip it. Then the next three digits are 059, which give the ID number 59. Next, 315 and 925- skip them. Then 252, 290, 045, so our first four Aucklanders sampled are 59, 252, 290, 45. That narrows it down to choices 3, 5: do you see how to pick the last one?

Comment: wooow so eaaasy , thanks a lot! really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sure, good luck on your test.